# Spring boot authentication in 2022

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have trouble with figuring out Spring Boot authentication. I am new to Spring Security and recently `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` got deprecated. Is there a source where basic authentication is explained and has some implementations of it?

I wasn't able to find something that would satisfy my request. New sources that I found, provided general view on it. The old ones were point at `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Basic Authentication has been the some for about 25+ years so not sure what you want to know about it. How to configure Spring Security is explained in that guide, how to change from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to the new one is explained in a blog https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter.

Comment: why not just read the official spring security documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring Security 5.7, You need to provide `SecurityFilterChain` bean.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .authenticationManager(new CustomAuthenticationManager());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

**Reference:** https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter